# Groovy - MissingPropertyException in Class

Tags: groovy

I am completely new to Groovy and having some trouble just getting this program running. All I'm trying to do is add all the elements of one list into another, but I can't even access the variable I want in the method.

I looked around here for an answer, but all seemed to be just too specific to a person's problem or too technical for my limited understanding of Groovy. Any help is appreciated.

Using `Groovy 2.4.5` in IntelliJ IDEA if that makes a difference. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
class ListPractice implements Testable {

    def mylist = [4,5,6]

    /**
     * Adds a set of elements to the mylist variable
     *
     * @paraelts The elements to be added
     */
    def addToList(List elts) {
        myList.each{
            println "I: $it"
        }
    }

    @Override
    void testMe() {
        addToList([7,8,9])
    }
}
```

But it throws the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myList
for class: ListPractice
Possible solutions: mylist
    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myList for class: ListPractice
Possible solutions: mylist
    at ListPractice.addToList(ListPractice.groovy:14)
    at ListPractice$addToList.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at ListPractice.testMe(ListPractice.groovy:36)
    at Testable$testMe.call(Unknown Source)
    at RunMe$_main_closure1.doCall(RunMe.groovy:12)
    at RunMe.main(RunMe.groovy:11)
```

Since this is my first time using the language and the structure of the code was done by my teacher, I'm not even sure if `@Override` is necessary or what it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Capitalisation is important

You declared your list as `mylist`

Then you try to call each on `myList`

It shows you in the error message

Comment: probably @TypeChecked would have helped

Comment: oh my... feel pretty silly about that one... Everything is good now, thanks. Guess I just needed a second set of eyes, mine weren't working properly.